# No errors but no 'Action'

Tags: php

I have searched and tried all the suggestions but no luck. Can you help someone who has come back to php, found php7 and is a little confused?

I have code for a simple login; I have a confirmed connection to MySQL and have (finally) eradicated all errors - but when I complete the fields I get nothing: no error message, not a message saying my password is either wrong or not recognized, not a message to say the email is in the wrong format - nothing. I should get a print saying, "You are logged in. Please click here" with a hyperlink.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    {
include_once 'mysqlconnect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';


$error = $user = $pass = "";

    $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM password
              WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";

    if (mysqli_num_rows(queryMysqli($query)) == 0)
    {
        $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
    }
    else
    {

        echo ("You are now logged in. Please
           <a href='C:\xampp/htdocs//xxxx/xxxc_member.php?view=$user'>click here</a>.");
    }
    }
    ?>
     <form action='valid.php' method='POST'> 

 <fieldset>         

    <legend>Enter a password and email address</legend>

        <p>Password : <input type='password' name='pass'></p> 
        <p>Email Address : <input type='text' name='user'></p> 

</fieldset>

<p><input type='submit' ></p> 

    </form>
```

And this is the relevant function:

```
    function querymysqli($query)
    {
    $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxxx', '', 'xxxxxx');
    {
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
return $result;
    }
    }
```

From this I am not getting any result. If someone could explain my error I would be very grateful - thank you.

Comment: You set `$user` and `$pass` to blank and then insert them into the query and check if the user credentials match?

Comment: Also `@mysqli_connect` specifically says to ignore the errors, so this could be failing.

Comment: Also, note that `mysqli_error()` must have your db link in argument: `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Nigel, Thanks for your advice: what do you recommend to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

It must be mysqli_query and not queryMysqli.

Comment: `queryMysqli()` is a function that wraps `mysqli_query()` (see code at bottom of question)